# Check if a CommandBarButton exists

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I'm using the following in the *ThisOutlookSession* of my VbaProject.OTM file to add 2 custom buttons to the new mail's *Standard* toolbar:

```vb
Dim outl As Object
Dim msg As Object
Set outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set msg = outl.CreateItem(0)
msg.Display (False)

Dim objBar As Office.CommandBar
Dim objButton As Office.CommandBarButton

Set objBar = Application.ActiveWindow.CommandBars("Standard")
Set objButton = objBar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)

With objButton
    .caption = "button1"
    .OnAction = "macro1"
    .TooltipText = "Description"
    .faceId = 487
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
    .BeginGroup = True
End With

Set objButton = objBar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)

With objButton
    .caption = "button2"
    .OnAction = "macro2"
    .TooltipText = "Description"
    .faceId = 2525
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
    .BeginGroup = True
End With

msg.Close 1
```

The problem is that the buttons will be added every time Outlook starts (which is needed for the other computers I'm willing to deploy my OTM file to). Is there any way to check before adding the buttons if it already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You buttons is a part of the `toolbar`. Hence check for the existance of the toolbar.

```
If IsToolbar("Standard") Then 
  '-- do something
  Else 
  '-- create tool bar and add the buttons
End If
```

Or try this:

```
For Each Contrl in Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls
   If .Caption <> "button1" then
      '-- create it
   End If
Next Contrl
```

---

### EDIT as per OP's comment:

So let's stick to the error catching... (untested code, so you may have to give it a try in your end for exact correct syntax)

```
Dim ctlCBarControl As CommandBarControl
On Error Resume Next    
Set ctlCBarControl = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("button1")

   If Err <> 0 Then
      '-- no button exists, you may add it
      Err = 0
   Else
      '-- the button is there.. 
   End If
End if
```

* Reference: [CommandBar Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141695%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the help. The second solution looks perfect. *Standard* is the default toolbar in Outlook by the way, checking if it exists doesn't help much but looping through the controls should do it. However, because this is the default toolbar, there is a ton of buttons. It will loop every time Outlook is launched. Which means I might be looking for a faster solution. No way to directly try to reach directly the right button with some *On Error* handle? Or I could just create a new toolbar I guess. I'm still looking for a guide on how to do this (create the toolbar, put it where I want, etc.).

Comment: @dnLL I think you are better off with a new `toolbar`, given that you can really add these two buttons into and trash it as you go ;) (Hoping that it's not too much for the front end to bear in terms of controls/elements you are loading to it..) I really don't have outlook at the moment to test for trial and error and I was just typing above code based on logic/syntax `;)` What you could do is try to catch the error as per my edit. +1 for your comment, you really came up with the faster solution you need perhaps. Let me know how it goes after you try the `err`

Comment: Controls.Item allows to pass the control name (a string). If the control with that name is not found, it will raise an exception that you can trap and insert your control.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko then it would work the way intended (without having to loop and lose precious milliseconds), however I think I might still go with a full new toolbar for my buttons, I will see what I can do about the position/size of the toolbar and everything without thrashing the user's configuration too much.

Comment: dnLL I have updated the code with an error check based on `caption`, please do refer to the MSDN site that I just happened to notice. @DmitryStreblechenko nice point `=)`

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try tomorrow once I figure out how to create a new toolbar.

Comment: Sure, but the,latter update doesn't require you to create a new toolbar. In that code `commandbarcontrol` is simply creating a control to be set by   toolbar controls caption - where it could raise an error... Anyway choose what's fast and best for you :-)  cheers.

Comment: Opted for that solution, with `On Error Resume Next` and then `On Error Goto 0`.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. It seems like the most easily managable option.